# JavaScript cannot find method a second time?

Tags: javascript, function, methods

I'm attempting to build a poker game. The method in question is very simple, and it works when it runs the first time.

This part isn't perfect convention because I'm just using it to test my methods:

```js
var $ = function (id) { return document.getElementById(id); };

var test = function() {
    var deck = new POKER.Deck();
    var hand = new POKER.Hand();

    for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++){
        hand.addCard(deck.dealCard());
    }

    hand.sortByRank();

    for (var j = 0; j < 7; j++){
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        var card = hand.getCardAtIndex(j); //** <------- WORKS HERE**
        img.src = card.getImage();
        $("images").appendChild(img);
    }

    var testHand = new POKER.Hand();
    testHand = hand.removePairs();

    for (var k = 0; k < testHand.length; k++) {
        var img2 = document.createElement("img");
        var card2 = testHand.getCardAtIndex(k); // **<------FAILS HERE**
        img2.src = card2.getImage();
        $("handImg").appendChild(img2);
    }
  };

window.onload = function() {
    test();
};
```

The first and second loop work, and the hand is displayed and everything. When it gets to the last loop, the debugger tells me "TypeError: testHand.getCardAtIndex is not a function"

I was attempting to test the removePairs method (to test for straights more easily), and when watching the variables in the debugger, testHand clearly gets populated correctly. The method seems to work just fine.

getCardAtIndex:

```js
POKER.Hand.prototype.getCardAtIndex = function(index) {
    return this.cards[index];
};
```

removePairs:

```js
POKER.Hand.prototype.removePairs = function(){
    var allCards = this.cards;
    var tempCards = [];
    var uniqueRanks = [];
    var unique;
    for(var i = 0; i < allCards.length; i++){
        unique = true;
        for(var j = 0; j < uniqueRanks.length; j++){
            if(allCards[i].getRank() == uniqueRanks[j]){
                unique = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(unique){
            uniqueRanks.push(allCards[i].getRank());
            tempCards.push(allCards[i]);
        }
    }
    return tempCards;
};
```

I'm completely perplexed.

Comment: `testHand = hand.removePairs();` will give you an array(tempCards). So you cannot call method of `Hand` on array object. Just go through the code again once or use debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var testHand = new POKER.Hand();
testHand = hand.removePairs();
```

`hand.removePairs()` returns an `Array`, not a `Hand` object. 
That's why you don't have access to the `getCardAtIndex` method.
If `cards` is a public property you could do:

```
testHand.cards = hand.removePairs();
```

Or you can have a setter method:

```
testHand.setCards(hand.removePairs);
```

Comment: I had to alter the removePairs so that it created a Hand object and returned it, but it worked! Thanks so much for the help!